# How to programatically insert python commands via Blender's C++ codebase

Tags: python, command-line

Hello Blender / Python gurus!

Is it possible to programatically feed python commands into Blender's python's console and catch the return values in Blender's C++ codebase?

I have added some C++ functionality to Blender for a game I'm designing and it would be very useful for my custom C++ Blender codebase to programatically insert Python command strings and catch the output.

In other words I would like to add a C++ function in Blender's code that accepts a string, inserts it into the Blender python console, runs it and catches the result printed to the console (all the while observing the result of each command inserted programmatically in the console window)

Currently I'm able to feed strings into a python interpreter from Blender's codebase but it is not the one used by the console window so I cannot view / edit its contents from the Blender GUI.

This would be great because Python's context can be explored via the visible Python console window in Blender to reveal its current state & global variable content.

Any ideas on where I might start?

Comment: If this is just for testing, why not just have the commands in a separate script in the blend file and not worry about feeding them in programatically?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. However, you can build your own [C and C++ Python Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/).

Comment: Thank you very much for these ideas.  Looking into this however I've found that the python editor console itself accepts clipboard pastes and runs that code.  As a result it would be possible to inject code through that technique.  I'll give this a try in a month or two and report back :)